# Next 25th day from now

Tags: php, datetime

I need a simple way of getting the next 25th from current date.

Example: If the date is 12/2 i need to get 25/2 . If the date is 25/2 or 28/2 the returning date would be 25/3. I'm using php Datetime.

I have been trying a few different methods using:

```
 $now = new DateTime("now");
 $date = new DateTime("first day of this month");
 $date->modify("+25 day");

 if($now->format("d") >= 25){
     $date->modify("+1 month");
 }
```

This code works. But there must be a simpler way... Anyone with a simpler solution?

I'm looking for something like (Or something like that)

```
 new DateTime("next 25th day");
```

Comment: http://il1.php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP 5.4 and above

```
$date = new DateTime( 
    (((new DateTime())->format('d') > 25) ? "next" : "this") . 
    " month + 24 days"
);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```